# Node WebDriverJS executeScript behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver

I have a WebDriverJS Node script with the following in the global scope of the application:

```
var helperFunctions = {
    'getElementEssentials': function get(orig, tmp, level) {
        var tmp = tmp || {};
        var level = level || 0;
        for(var i in orig) {
            if(!orig[i]) { continue; }
            if(typeof(orig[i]) === 'function' || typeof(orig[i]) === 'object' || level > 1) { continue; }
            if(typeof(orig[i]) === 'array') { level++; get(orig[i], tmp, level); continue; }
            tmp[i] = orig[i]; continue;
        }
        return tmp;
    }
};
```

I want to pass this function in to `driver.executeScript` using something like this:

```
var evalSelectAll = function(selector, getElementEssentials) {

    var els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    var els2 = [];
    for(var i in els) {
        els2.push(getElementEssentials(els[i]));
    }

    var elsStringified = JSON.stringify(els2);

    return elsStringified;

};

driver.executeScript(evalSelectAll, selector, helperFunctions.getElementEssentials).then( function(data) {
    // things
});
```

`selector` relates to a CSS selector expression, so "a" or "div > h1" for example.

My understanding of executeScript is that for the first argument it can accept either a string or a function - a string will be evaluated on the target page, and a function will be executed on the target page, and that all subsequent arguments are additional data?

I get the following error when trying to run this (note that to keep things simple I just passed in a test object of `{test: true}`:

```
D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1643
      throw error;
            ^
UnknownError: {"errorMessage":"'function get(orig, tmp, level) {\r\n\t    var tmp = tmp || {};\r\n\t    var level = level || 0;\r\n\t    for(var i in orig) {\r\n\t        if(!orig[i]) { continue; }\r\n\t        if(typeof(orig[i]) === 'function' || typeof(orig[i]) === 'object' || level > 1) { continue; }\r\n\t        if(typeof(orig[i]) === 'array') { level++; get(orig[i], tmp, level); continue; }\r\n\t        tmp[i] = orig[i]; continue;\r\n\t    }\r\n\t    return tmp;\r\n\t}' is not a function (evaluating 'getElementEssentials({test: true})')","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Connection":"keep-alive","Content-Length":"903","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"192.168.0.7:56849"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"script\":\"return (function (selector, getElementEssentials) {\\r\\n\\r\\n\\t\\t\\treturn getElementEssentials({test: true});\\r\\n\\r\\n\\t\\t\\tvar els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t/*var els2 = [];\\r\\n\\t\\t\\tfor(var i in els) {\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\tels2.push(getElementEssentials(els[i]));\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t}\\r\\n\\r\\n\\t\\t\\tvar elsStringified = JSON.stringify(els2);\\r\\n\\r\\n\\t\\t\\treturn elsStringified;*/\\r\\n\\r\\n\\t\\t}).apply(null, arguments);\",\"args\":[\"h1\",\"function get(orig, tmp, level) {\\r\\n\\t    var tmp = tmp || {};\\r\\n\\t    var level = level || 0;\\r\\n\\t    for(var i in orig) {\\r\\n\\t
     if(!orig[i]) { continue; }\\r\\n\\t        if(typeof(orig[i]) === 'function' || typeof(orig[i]) === 'object' || level > 1) { continue; }\\r\\n\\t        if(typeof(orig[i]) === 'array') { level++; get(orig[i], tmp, level); continue; }\\r\\n\\t        tmp[i] = orig[i]; continue;\\r\\n\\t    }\\r\\n\\t    return tmp;\\r\\n\\t}\"]}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/c18c1ff0-0f25-11e4-a90e-a36273e3866b/execute"}}
    at new bot.Error (D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:109:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\response.js:106:9)
    at D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:277:20
    at D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1243:15
    at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1539:20)
    at notify (D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:362:12)
    at notifyAll (D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:331:7)
    at resolve (D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:309:7)
    at fulfill (D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:429:5)
    at D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1406:10
==== async task ====
WebDriver.executeScript()
    at webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:268:15)
    at webdriver.WebDriver.executeScript (D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:404:15)
    at D:\Git\mateserver\main.js:174:11
    at D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1243:15
    at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1539:20)
    at notify (D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:362:12)
    at notifyAll (D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:331:7)
    at resolve (D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:309:7)
    at fulfill (D:\Git\mateserver\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:429:5)
```

Any thoughts on this? Am I using executeScript correctly? Thanks.

Update: It seems that if I put the `get` function inside the `evalSelectAll` function then it works. It seems as though passing functions as arguments to `executeScript` is not supported. Can anybody confirm this? It would be nice to have the code be more reusable by staying outside the eval function.